# Very ugly stretched Text

Tags: line-breaking

I got an enumeration within multicols that's very ugly stretched when there's a line break. How can I prevent this?

[image]

Comment: If the wording and column width are fixed, you have three choices. (a) live with the space (b) let the line fall short after the second word (raggedright setting or just force that line with `\\ `) (c) hyphenate the third word.  The solution depends on which you want....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
...
\usepackage{ragged2e}
...

{\RaggedRight
\begin{enumerate}
\item ...
...
\end{enumerate}}
```

Comment: Why not `\RaggedRight` just after `\begin{enumerate}`, that avoids the need of additional braces?